# Como hacer este tipo de borde en CSS

Tags: html, css

No soy capaz de hacer este tipo de borde con CSS.

Lo máximo que consigo es esto, pero la línea no baja:

```css
cuerpo {
  padding:10px;
  border-top: solid #3E9722 0.4em;
  border-radius: 2em 2em 
}
```

[image: Bordes]

Comment: Hola Javier, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código, te recomiendo ver [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y obtengas una mejor respuesta, y de paso evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.
Y de paso, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: Si tienes acceso a ver ese sitio web, click derecho, inspeccionar elemento... Ver lo que hay en el CSS y estudiarlo :D Puedes habilitar y deshabilitar propiedades a la volada, es una pasada :D

Answer (score 2):

Tenes que indicar:

- Para la propiedad [`border-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-width) el `top left bottom right`, por ejemplo:

  ```
  border-width: 0.4em 0.4em 0 0.4em;
  ```
- Para la propiedad [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius) el `top left bottom right`, por ejemplo:

  ```
  border-radius: 2em 2em 0 0;
  ```

#### Demo:

```css
.mi-borde {
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid #3E9722;
  border-width: 0.4em 0.4em 0 0.4em;
  border-radius: 2em 2em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="mi-borde">
  <p>Texto largo para que se vea como queda</p>
</div>
```

---

Para lograr el efecto en el cuerpo, podes hacer uso de la propiedades `position` y `height`.

- Creamos un elemento con `position: absolute` y `height` fijo
- Para evitar que elemento anterior se vaya de lugar, necesitamos crear un contenedor (*`.cuerpo`*) al cual le configuramos `position: relative`.

#### Ejemplo:

```css
.mi-borde {
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid #3E9722;
  border-width: 0.4em 0.4em 0 0.4em;
  border-radius: 2em 2em 0 0;
}
.cuerpo {
  position: relative;
  padding: calc(10px + .4em); // padding + border-raduis 
}
.efecto-cuerpo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cuerpo">
  <div class="mi-borde efecto-cuerpo"></div>
  <p>Texto largo para que se vea como queda</p>
  <p>Texto largo para que se vea como queda</p>
  <p>Texto largo para que se vea como queda</p>
  <p>Texto largo para que se vea como queda</p>
  <p>Texto largo para que se vea como queda</p>
  <p>Texto largo para que se vea como queda</p>
  <p>Texto largo para que se vea como queda</p>
  <p>Texto largo para que se vea como queda</p>
  <p>Texto largo para que se vea como queda</p>
  <p>Texto largo para que se vea como queda</p>
  <p>Texto largo para que se vea como queda</p>
  <p>Texto largo para que se vea como queda</p>
  <p>Texto largo para que se vea como queda</p>
  <p>Texto largo para que se vea como queda</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, eso para el div del "pie de página" podría funcionar, pero el div del cuerpo ocupa todo el cuerpo de la pagina, por lo que la linea llega hasta abajo, y a mi me gustaría que fuese solo un trozo, como en la imagen

Comment: @Javier, he actualizado mi respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Algo más simple sería darle una **altura fija** al contenedor que tendrán esos bordes para que siempre tenga esa altura a pesar de que el contenido de adentro sea más grande que el contenedor, es decir, si el contenido supera al alto del contenedor, la altura del contenedor no va a cambiar porque **su altura es fija**:

```
.contenedor {
  height: 100px;
  border: solid green;
  border-width: 8px 8px 0 8px;
  border-radius: 30px 30px 0 0;
}
```

Te doy un ejemplo con `cards` de bootstrap v5, para que notes como a pesar del cambio de alto del contenido, la altura del contenedor sigue siendo la misma:

```css
.contenedor {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid green;
  border-width: 8px 8px 0 8px;
  border-radius: 30px 30px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class ="contenedor">
  <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
      <div class="card h-100">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/wBWzOZo.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to
            additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
      <div class="card h-100">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/wBWzOZo.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to
            additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
      <div class="card h-100">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/wBWzOZo.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to
            additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
      <div class="card h-100">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/wBWzOZo.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to
            additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

---

Puedes ver mejor los resultados en [**este enlace**](https://codepen.io/christopher-ps/pen/VwBJoJj).

Comment: No fui yo el del punto negativo, pero este código no funcionará bien cuando hay más elementos en la página. Se aprovecha de que el overflow es visible, pero eso no quiere decir que empuje a los elementos posteriors, sólo se solapan que puede no ser lo que busca el usuario en la pregunta.